# No Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, view

I am getting a `NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` on the following code.

Show view:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  ...
```

Users controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :layout => false
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the BluePlaque Explorer!"
      redirect_to @user 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

  def login
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

The show view what displays user's profile page after successful registration. Cannot see what causes it.

Comment: Check if that user has a name.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass

Apart from the apparent fact you don't have a `.name` method for your `User` model, there is another problem highlighted by this error... that your `@user` variable is not set.

---

`Rails`/`Ruby` doesn't handle "undeclared" variables in the expected way; it assigns them to `nil:NilClass` - it messes up developer's minds because they think the *method* is the error, when really, it's the lack of `@object` to call the method on.

The bottom line is that you need the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will set your `@user` variable, with which you'll be able to call `.name` or whatever:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= @user.first_name %>
```

--

Now... a cool trick for you:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def name
      first_name + " " + last_name
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call `@user.name` *if* `@user` is set!

Answer (score 0):

You always have able to use  `try` if not sure about presense

`<% provide(:title, @user.try(:name)) %>`